# Сообщение об удалении при Swipe to dismiss

Tags: android, recyclerview

Всем привет. Как стандартными средствами можно реализовать сообщение под удаляемым элементом из RecyclerView, к примеру, как в Gmail? Как на картинке, иконка ящика.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добрый день! Решили вопрос? тоже актуально...

Answer (score 1):

Можешь попробовать эту библиотеку:
    https://github.com/tycallen/SwipeMenu-Expandable-ListView